# Maven Shade External Properties file relative to final Jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

**Hi all!!**

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm new to Maven and have reached an impasse!

1. I have a project which uses MyTest.properties, MoreMyTest.properties.
2. I use the Maven Shade plugin to build this project into a .jar file, which is working fine! Unfortunately, the shade plugin is packaging MyTest.properties inside my jar file.

Then, I get this error when I try to execute the jar.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate: properties/MyTest.properties at file:\C:\Dev\test.jar!\properties\MyTest.properties
>               at ...

I'm wanting to access my properties both inside my IDE, and by running the jar from the command line when I deploy. I was thinking of having my properties files in a relative folder ../lib/ above the location of my jar file.

Inside my program I want to access the properties like so:

```
File testProperties = new File(
  ClassLoader.getSystemResource("properties/MyTest.properties").getFile()
);
```

I tried adding this to my POM.xml

```xml
<transformer
    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
  <resource>*.properties</resource>
  <file>../*properties</file>
</transformer>
```

(Sorry the formatting got messed on the above code snippet!)

But, it's not working. I'd really appreciate any help in this. I've not posted all code as the code is really big, but I hope you can get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: I'm not sure you're having a maven shade plugin problem; I think you're having a properties file problem.  Consider using a system property that points to the location of your props file.  System properties can be set at runtime on the command line and/or programmatically so they end up being pretty flexible for this kind of thing

Comment: Hi @wax_lyrical I am facing exactly the same problem with apache maven shade plugin, have you got any solution to this? please post

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have a solution. Always the way, just after posting! But thanks for your reply.

```
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>../lib</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This was the only way I could get to "shade" properties files using maven shade plugin.  Using IncludeResourceTransfomer, didn't seem to help me; the maven documentation surrounding the use of the transformer also was quite limited.